# How do I scrape Prometheus metrics from two endpoints for the same Kubernetes pods?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, containers, monitoring, prometheus

I want to scrape metrics from two endpoints for the same pods - /demo/v1.0/metrics and /actuator/prometheus. This is how my annotations in values.yaml looks like right now.

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    iam.amazonaws.com/role: xxxx
    prometheus.io/app: DEMO_SERVICE
    prometheus.io/env: PRODUCTION
    prometheus.io/path: /demo/v1.0/metrics
    prometheus.io/port: "8197"
    prometheus.io/product: DEMO_SERVICE
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    prometheus.io/service: DEMO_SERVICE
    prometheus.io/team: PROCESSING
```

How do I add the actuator endpoint to it and is it even required? I have added the Micrometer Prometheus registry dependency to pom.xml and I'm able to see the actuator metrics locally. Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?